Correct option to download from youtube with video resolution of 1080p using youtube-dl?
To download youtube videos manually I typically use : https://y2meta.app/en/youtube/rU8_Fg103ZQ 's
[1080p (.mp4) full-HD] resolution.
Now I am looking to replicate the same via code using python's library youtube-dl . As per documentations ydl_opts
is what I need to confugure properly.
My hunch say  "format": "bestvideo[height=1080]/best[height=1080]", should be what I should set but I find it errors out with the following:
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: requested format not available

or for "format": "mp4+bestvideo[height=1080]"I get
ERROR: giving up after 0 fragment retries
Among all permutation that I tried I found What doesn't error out is this:
        ydl_opts = {
            "format": "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=mp4]/mp4+best[height<=720]",
            "recode-video": "mp4",
            "outtmpl": '/my/video/output/path',
        }


but here I get a resolution with height of mere 360p. I need height to be 1080p.
PS: I dont care much about the audio, a mute mp4 with height = 1080p is enough for me.
EDIT:
As a workaround I am doing this,
        ydl_opts = {
            "format": "bestvideo[ext=mp4]",
            "merge_output_format": "mp4",
        }

and then downscaling to 1080p locally but this has an issue as well it is donloading partially ie only 1 minites and creates the illusion the full file has downloaded(ie no error thrown nor any part files).It shows Skipping fragment warning message only.
[download]  25.0% of ~80.00MiB at  3.46MiB/s ETA 00:17[download] Skipping fragment 3...
[download] Skipping fragment 4...
[download] Skipping fragment 5...
[download] Skipping fragment 6...
[download] Skipping fragment 7...
[download] Skipping fragment 8...
[download] 100% of 20.00MiB in 00:06


Are you sure the original video was in HD?  If the video was recorded in 360p, then that's all you can get.

@TimRoberts I am not sure of anything which is why I am here. I have shared the link of the video under experiment as well. If it worked via manual download from that site it should work via code as well is what my point it

@TimRoberts in fact if I specify "format": "mp4+bestvideo" it is downloading far beyond 1080p but it is erroring while merging the file.(I checked resolution from part files)
